# Django URL does not change after Redirection

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-1.7

I'm learning Django 1.7 through an online book "Tango with Django 1.7".

This tutorial creates a "Link Directory" which has categories and web links relating to the categories.

When I add a page to a category say "django" using following url:

```
http://localhost:8000/rango/category/django/add_page/
```

I redirect (redirect to category page) after successful execution of the page addition using following return statement

```
return category(request, category_name_slug)
```

Though the redirect works successfully but the url in browser does not change to

```
http://localhost:8000/rango/category/django/
```

and it remains the same

```
http://localhost:8000/rango/category/django/add_page/
```

What should I do to change the url too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This actually helped me.  I was looking for a way to NOT change the URL.  Doing this way did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the view `category(request, category_name_slug)` is not actually a redirect. To request you should use `HttpResponseRedirect()` and do something like

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("<your_category_url>", 
                           <kw_params_of_your_url>))
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't redirect.  `return category(request, category_name_slug)` just returns the response of the view without any redirection.

Use [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect('name-of-category-url', category_name_slug)
```

BTW, if your `Category` model has `get_absolute_url()` method then you can redirect to desired category instance without messing with url names/parameters:

```
return redirect(category)
```